# Возврат списка с копиями элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, yield

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне получить с помощью `yield` список, который должен содержать n копий этого элемента. Моя функция:

```
def replicate(value, lst):
    for i in lst:
        yield [i] * value

print(list(replicate(3, [1, "z"])))  # ==> [[1, 1, 1], ['z', 'z', 'z']]
```

Пример правильного вывода:

```
list(replicate(1, [1, 'z']))  # [1, 'z']
list(replicate(0, [1, 'z']))  # []
list(replicate(5, [1, 'z']))  # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z']
```

Если использую `yield i * value`то получаю [3, 'zzz']. Может быть требуется выпрямление списка

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всего лишь вынести количество в еще один цикл

```
def replicate(value, lst):
    for i in lst:
        for _ in range(value):
            yield i
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 4):

есть такая конструкция:

```
def replicate(value, lst):
    for i in lst:
        yield from [i] * value

>>> list(replicate(5, [1, 'z']))  # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z']
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!